# I like "the" music or I like music?

Tags: differences

1. I like music.
2. I like the music.

I know the difference between the previous two sentences is that 'the music' is specifically talking about a music.

Is there any more difference in meaning? Can you tell me some cases where the definite article isn't required?

Comment: Hey rakaknoh, we have a StackExchange site dedicated for just these kinds of questions: [ELL](http://ell.staxkexchange,com). You might like to ask this question there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you got it just fine:

You use the article when refering to some *specific instance* of something,

 without article, you are making a *general statement*, often about the *type* of something.

Some examples:

> "I like fish" (...but don't like pork) vs. "I like **the** fish" (...which is on my plate.)
>
> "I dread christmas" (...because it's always such a hassle) vs. "I dread **this** christmas" (...because my Mum died last month.)
>
> "I see clouds" (here, whereas you, somewhere else, see sunshine.) vs. "I see **the** clouds" (...threatening to rain on my laundry and yours.)